# Unable to show svg in Content Manager Explorer

Tags: cme, sites-9, multimedia, component

I've uploaded several svg-s into Multimedia Components. When browsing the CME Folder containing those Components, the CME shows a default mm-icon instead of the content of the svg. Svg is defined as mime-type in both CME (Sites 9.0)(manually added) and IIS.

It would be nice if our editors could pick the right svg by viewing the svg and not only by name. Anyone any suggestions?

Comment: Theo did you recently did upgrade to sites 9 or it’s a fresh install .

Comment: We did a upgrade a few months ago (from Tridion 2011)

Answer (score 5):

Support for Scalable Vector Graphics was introduced in Tridion Sites 9.1: https://docs.sdl.com/816112/750876/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5/content-manager-explorer-and-experience-manager-functionality-introduced-in-------------sdl-tridion-sites-9-1

Answer (score 0):

the only thing I can think of is that you need to write a GUI extension to see it. You will have to write it for the component view editor. Besides that, since you mention it's on 9.1, it might be worth seeing what's possible in the new Experience Space related to SVG in the 9.5 release.